# Jump to the first file or directory that starts with a specific letter

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the VS Code Explorer, how do jump to the first file or directory that starts with a specific letter?

For example, in the `node_modules` directory, I want to be able to press <kbd>W</kbd> and jump to `wcwidth` in the following directory list.

```
.bin
abbrev
accepts
acorn
after
agent-base
align-text
amdefine
ansi-align
ansi-regex
ansi-styles
ansicolors
any-promise
anymatch
archy
argparse
arr-diff
arr-flatten
array-differ
array-find-index
array-slice
array-uniq
array-unique
arraybuffer.slice
arrify
asn1
assert-plus
async
async-done
async-each
async-each-series
async-settle
atob
aurelia-animator-css
aurelia-binding
aurelia-bootstrapper
aurelia-cli
aurelia-dependency-injection
aurelia-event-aggregator
aurelia-fetch-client
aurelia-framework
aurelia-history
aurelia-history-browser
aurelia-loader
aurelia-loader-default
aurelia-logging
aurelia-logging-console
aurelia-metadata
aurelia-pal
aurelia-pal-browser
aurelia-path
aurelia-polyfills
aurelia-route-recognizer
aurelia-router
aurelia-task-queue
aurelia-templating
aurelia-templating-binding
aurelia-templating-resources
aurelia-templating-router
aurelia-testing
aurelia-tools
aws-sign2
bach
backo2
balanced-match
base64-arraybuffer
base64id
batch
beeper
benchmark
better-assert
binary-extensions
bl
blob
bluebird
body-parser
boom
boxen
brace-expansion
braces
breeze-dag
breeze-nexttick
breeze-queue
browser-sync
browser-sync-client
browser-sync-ui
bs-recipes
builtin-modules
bytes
callsite
camelcase
camelcase-keys
capture-stack-trace
cardinal
caseless
center-align
chalk
chokidar
cli-boxes
cli-table
cli-usage
cliui
clone
clone-stats
code-point-at
colors
columnify
combined-stream
commander
component-bind
component-emitter
component-inherit
concat-map
concat-stream
configstore
connect
connect-history-api-fallback
content-type
convert-source-map
core-js
core-util-is
create-error-class
cryptiles
css
ctype
currently-unhandled
custom-event
d
dateformat
debug
decamelize
deep-extend
deep-is
default-resolution
defaults
delayed-stream
depd
destroy
detect-file
detect-indent
detect-newline
dev-ip
di
diff
dom-serialize
dot-prop
duplexer
duplexer2
duplexify
easy-extender
eazy-logger
ee-first
emitter-steward
end-of-stream
engine.io
engine.io-client
engine.io-parser
ent
error-ex
es5-ext
es6-iterator
es6-symbol
es6-weak-map
escape-html
escape-string-regexp
escodegen
esprima-fb
estraverse
esutils
etag
event-stream
eventemitter3
expand-braces
expand-brackets
expand-range
expand-tilde
express
extend
extend-shallow
extglob
fancy-log
fast-levenshtein
filename-regex
fileset
fill-range
filled-array
finalhandler
find-up
findup-sync
fined
first-chunk-stream
flagged-respawn
for-in
for-own
forever-agent
form-data
formidable
fresh
from
fs-access
fs-exists-sync
fs-extra
fs.realpath
function-bind
gaia-tsort
generate-function
generate-object-property
get-stdin
glob
glob-base
glob-parent
glob-stream
glob-watcher
global-modules
global-prefix
glogg
got
graceful-fs
graceful-readlink
growly
gulp
gulp-changed-in-place
gulp-notify
gulp-plumber
gulp-rename
gulp-sourcemaps
gulp-tslint
gulp-typescript
gulp-util
gulplog
handlebars
har-validator
has
has-ansi
has-binary
has-cors
has-flag
has-gulplog
hawk
hoek
hosted-git-info
http-errors
http-proxy
http-proxy-agent
http-signature
https-proxy-agent
iconv-lite
immutable
imurmurhash
indent-string
indexof
inflight
inherits
ini
interpret
invariant
invert-kv
is
is-absolute
is-arrayish
is-binary-path
is-buffer
is-builtin-module
is-dotfile
is-equal-shallow
is-extendable
is-extglob
is-finite
is-fullwidth-code-point
is-glob
is-my-json-valid
is-npm
is-number
is-obj
is-plain-obj
is-posix-bracket
is-primitive
is-property
is-redirect
is-relative
is-retry-allowed
is-stream
is-unc-path
is-utf8
is-valid-glob
is-windows
isarray
isbinaryfile
isexe
isobject
isstream
istanbul
jasmine-core
js-tokens
js-yaml
json-stable-stringify
json-stringify-safe
json3
jsonfile
jsonify
jsonpointer
jsrsasign
jwt-decode
karma
karma-chrome-launcher
karma-cli
karma-coverage
karma-firefox-launcher
karma-jasmine
karma-requirejs
karma-spec-reporter
karma-typescript-preprocessor
kind-of
klaw
last-run
latest-version
lazy-cache
lazy-req
lazystream
lcid
levn
liftoff
limiter
listify
load-json-file
localtunnel
lockfile
lodash
lodash.assign
lodash.assignwith
lodash.clonedeep
lodash.debounce
lodash.defaults
lodash.escape
lodash.filter
lodash.flatten
lodash.foreach
lodash.initial
lodash.isarguments
lodash.isarray
lodash.isempty
lodash.isequal
lodash.isfunction
lodash.isplainobject
lodash.isstring
lodash.keys
lodash.last
lodash.map
lodash.mapvalues
lodash.pick
lodash.reduce
lodash.restparam
lodash.sortby
lodash.template
lodash.templatesettings
lodash._arraycopy
lodash._arrayeach
lodash._baseassign
lodash._baseclone
lodash._basecopy
lodash._basefor
lodash._basetostring
lodash._basevalues
lodash._bindcallback
lodash._createassigner
lodash._getnative
lodash._isiterateecall
lodash._reescape
lodash._reevaluate
lodash._reinterpolate
lodash._root
log4js
longest
loose-envify
loud-rejection
lowercase-keys
lru-cache
make-error
make-error-cause
map-cache
map-obj
map-stream
marked
marked-terminal
matchdep
media-typer
meow
merge-stream
micromatch
mime
mime-db
mime-types
minimatch
minimist
mkdirp
ms
multipipe
mute-stdout
negotiator
next-tick
node-emoji
node-notifier
node-status-codes
node-uuid
node.extend
nopt
normalize-package-data
normalize-path
now-and-later
npm
null-check
number-is-nan
oauth-sign
object-assign
object-component
object-path
object.omit
object.pick
on-finished
once
openurl
opn
optimist
optionator
options
ordered-read-streams
os-homedir
os-locale
os-tmpdir
osenv
package-json
parse-filepath
parse-glob
parse-json
parsejson
parseqs
parseuri
parseurl
path-exists
path-is-absolute
path-root
path-root-regex
path-type
pause-stream
pify
pinkie
pinkie-promise
pkg-conf
popsicle
popsicle-proxy-agent
popsicle-retry
popsicle-status
portscanner
prelude-ls
prepend-http
preserve
pretty-hrtime
process-nextick-args
promise-finally
qs
randomatic
range-parser
raw-body
rc
read-all-stream
read-pkg
read-pkg-up
readable-stream
readdirp
rechoir
redent
redeyed
regex-cache
registry-url
repeat-element
repeat-string
repeating
replace-ext
request
require-main-filename
requirejs
requires-port
resolve
resolve-dir
resolve-url
resp-modifier
right-align
rimraf
rx
semver
semver-diff
semver-greatest-satisfied-range
semver-regex
send
serve-index
serve-static
server-destroy
set-blocking
set-immediate-shim
setprototypeof
shellwords
signal-exit
slide
sntp
socket.io
socket.io-adapter
socket.io-client
socket.io-parser
sort-keys
source-map
source-map-resolve
source-map-url
sparkles
spdx-correct
spdx-exceptions
spdx-expression-parse
spdx-license-ids
split
sprintf-js
stack-trace
statuses
stream-combiner
stream-exhaust
stream-shift
stream-throttle
string-template
string-width
stringstream
string_decoder
strip-ansi
strip-bom
strip-bom-stream
strip-indent
strip-json-comments
supports-color
symbol
text
tfunk
thenify
throat
through
through2
through2-filter
throwback
tildify
time-stamp
timed-out
to-absolute-glob
to-array
touch
tough-cookie
trim-newlines
tslint
tunnel-agent
type-check
type-is
typedarray
typescript
typings
typings-core
ua-parser-js
uglify-js
uglify-to-browserify
ultron
unc-path-regex
underscore
underscore.string
undertaker
undertaker-registry
unique-stream
unpipe
unzip-response
update-notifier
urix
url-parse-lax
user-home
useragent
utf8
util-deprecate
utils-merge
uuid
v8flags
vali-date
validate-npm-package-license
vinyl
vinyl-fs
void-elements
wcwidth
weinre
whatwg-fetch
which
widest-line
window-size
wordwrap
wrap-ansi
wrappy
wreck
write-file-atomic
ws
xdg-basedir
xmlhttprequest-ssl
xtend
y18n
yargs
yargs-parser
yeast
zip-object
```

This already works in the Windows File Explorer. It's called "When typing into list view, Select the typed item in the view." Does a similar feature exist in the Visual Studio Code Explorer?